# How to solve css issue to display image caption?

Tags: html, css

I want to display some image with caption.By default its showing image only but I want to display image with caption by default.I am giving my css and html code below :

```
   <style type="text/css">

    .caption-style-1{
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;

    }

    .caption-style-1 li{
        float: left;
        padding: 0px;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin-right:5px;
    }

    .caption-style-1 li:hover .caption{
        opacity: 1;

    }

    .caption-style-1 .hover-effect{
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        float: left;
        width:220px;
        height:150px;
        //background-color:#999;
        margin-bottom:5px;
    }

    .hover-effect img{
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        float: left;
        z-index: 4;
    }
    .hover-effect h1
    {
        font-size:20px;
        border:solid 1px red;
    }

    .hover-effect p
    {
        font-size:13px;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }


    .caption-style-1 .caption{
        cursor: pointer;
        position: absolute;
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transition:all 0.45s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition:all 0.45s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition:all 0.45s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition:all 0.45s ease-in-out;
        transition:all 0.45s ease-in-out;

    }
    .caption-style-1 .blur{
        //background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
        height: 150px;
        width: 220px;
        z-index: 5;
        position: absolute;
    }

    .caption-style-1 .caption-text h1{
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 10px;
    }
    .caption-style-1 .caption-text .blur{
        z-index: 10;
        color: #fff;
        position: absolute;
        width: 220px;
        height: 150px;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
    }

    /** Nav Menu */
    ul.nav-menu{
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        list-style-type: none;
        width: 490px;
        margin: 60px auto;
    }

    ul.nav-menu li{
        display: inline;
        margin-right: 10px;
        padding:10px;
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
    }

    ul.nav-menu li a{
        color: #eee;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    ul.nav-menu li a:hover, ul.nav-menu li a.active{
        color: #2c3e50;
    } 

    .opacity
    {
        opacity:0.2;
        filter:alpha(opacity=20); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    }

    </style>
```

And my html code's are given below :

```
<ul class="caption-style-1">
   <li>
     <div class="hover-effect">
         <div class="opacity"><img src="img/chaps_1x.jpg" width="220px" height="150px" alt=""></div>
          <h1>Amazing Caption</h1>
      <p>Whatever It Is - Always Awesome</p>
     </div>

     <div class="caption">
    <div class="blur"></div>
      <div class="caption-text">
        <img src="img/chaps_1x.jpg" width="220px" height="150px" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Any Idea?

Comment: Please create a JSFiddle.

Comment: It looks like you have introduced some hover behaviour, but you haven't provided a description about it... is it relevant?

Comment: Here is the js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7Su6F/1/

Comment: Please check my js fiddle,you will understand what I exactly want to do @Chris Hardie

Comment: My problem is everything working fine but by default image caption is not showing.Please check my js fiddle. Thanks @Paulie_D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML code is not written in well manner. If you using HTML5 then you may use HTML5 tags like `figcaption` with `figure`. The Caption tag is not showing in your style because they are behind the image.

So here is the way to move to front using `z-index` property.

```
 .hover-effect h1
    {
        font-size:20px;
        border:solid 1px red;
      position:fixed;
        z-index:999;
    }

    .hover-effect p
    {
        font-size:13px;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
       position:fixed;
        z-index:999;
    }
```

Here is the Demo. http://jsbin.com/yegiyico/1/

Comment: h1 and p will not be fixed.It appear by default.But onHover,caption text will go away.I need something like that

Comment: do you want like this? on hover text hide? check Demo. http://jsbin.com/yegiyico/2/

Comment: yes,exactly this one.Can you give me the code please?Also h1 and p will not be fixed position.

Comment: just open the link and on the right side of the page you can see edit button. yes you can change the position anything you want..but remember if you giving position:absolute; then the parent div must have the relative position, so it doesn't go out of the flow.

Comment: I am not able to view the code and can you please take a look by changing position?It will great if you try this please,thanks.

Comment: okay, here is the code. now the caption is at bottom.  I hope your problem is solved now. http://jsbin.com/yegiyico/3/edit